# Initialize firebase in index.html file, but index.js throws a ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I initialize`firebase` in index.html. But the line `const db = firebase.firestore();` throws an error in `index.js`.

**Should firebase be in scope, since I load all the firebase modules in `index.html` and initialize firebase and then load `index.js?**

Error:   `ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`
Structure of application:

```
/
|--functions
     |
     |---- index.js
|--public
     |
     |---- index.html
     |---- app.js
```

index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true});
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
```

app.js:

```
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/',
    callbacks: {signInSuccess: true},
    signInOptions: [
        {
            provider:firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            requireDisplayName: false
        },
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        {
            provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            recaptchaParameters: {size: 'invisible'},
        }
    ],
};

ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
if (ui.isPendingRedirect()) {ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);}

var handleSignedInUser = function(user) {
    console.log('LOOOOOGGGG');
    document.getElementById('user-signed-in').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('user-signed-out').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('name').textContent = user.displayName ? user.displayName : user.phoneNumber;
    document.getElementById('email').textContent = user.email;
    document.getElementById('phone').textContent = user.phoneNumber;
    if (user.photoURL) {
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        // Append size to the photo URL for Google hosted images to avoid requesting
        // the image with its original resolution (using more bandwidth than needed)
        // when it is going to be presented in smaller size.
        if ((photoURL.indexOf('googleusercontent.com') != -1) ||
            (photoURL.indexOf('ggpht.com') != -1)) {
            photoURL = photoURL + '?sz=' +
                document.getElementById('photo').clientHeight;
        }
        document.getElementById('photo').src = photoURL;
        document.getElementById('photo').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('photo').style.display = 'none';
    }
    nameinDB = usersRef.where("name","==",user.name);
    emailinDB = usersRef.where("name","==",user.email);

    console.log(nameinDB);
    console.log(emailinDB);
    console.log("bort");

};

var handleSignedOutUser = function() {
    document.getElementById('user-signed-in').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('user-signed-out').style.display = 'block';
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
};

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('loaded').style.display = 'block';
    user ? handleSignedInUser(user) : handleSignedOutUser();
});

function recaptchaVerifierInvisible() {
    function onSignInSubmit() {
      // TODO(you): Implement
    }
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {
        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
        onSignInSubmit();
      }
    });
  }
  

 var initApp = function() {
    document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked log out');
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    });
};

window.addEventListener('load', initApp);
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': (response) => {onSignInSubmit();}
});

//DB 
console.log(auth);
```

index.html

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Imperial Zhao</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    <script>
       var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyB_8VRAvuzIvPyFGbL4sX4VA_pa7V0LJjE",
            authDomain: "zhaobot.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://zhaobot-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "zhaobot",
            storageBucket: "zhaobot.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "40454341298",
            appId: "1:40454341298:web:5d9b4554f7c1296c507fab",
            measurementId: "G-1J082S2W8B"
            };
      
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
  
    <script src="functions/index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <h1>The Imperial Zhao</h1>
    <div id="loading">Loading...</div>

    <div id="loaded" class="hidden">
        <div id="user-signed-out" class="hidden">
            <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="user-signed-in" class="hidden">    
            <div id="userDetails">
                <div id="name"></div>
            </div>    
            <button id="sign-out" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Out</button>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase is not defined
```

means that you haven't imported firebase in the file.

There are so many firebase libraries so I cannot spot which one here, but I am sure you know which one you are using.

Judging fron the error, all you need is:

```
const firebase = require('...');
```

Comment: Doesn't the first script tag in index.html import it?

Comment: but it is undefined when the code in index.js runs. Make sure "firebase" is available if you don't want to include it in index.js.

Comment: But `console.log(firebase)` correctly prints if I put it after `initializeApp` in the HTML. I load `index.js` after those statements with `defer`. Why does firebase drop out of scope and become undefined? Also if I `var firebase = require('firebase')`, then `firebase.firestore` is undefined, although that may be a separate error.

Comment: I believe functions/index.js is not browser JavaScript but server side. Therefore, importing firebase in index.js is necessary.

Comment: Do you have node_modules inside functions/ right?